# получить текст от бота telegram python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

всем привет, пишу бота на pytelegrambotapi и появилась такая проблема:
нужно чтобы бот получал сообщения от другого бота в приватном чате, пробовал через

```
msg = str(message)
print(msg)
file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
print(file_info)
downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
src = dirlogs + message.document.file_name;
with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
 new_file.write(downloaded_file)
 new_file.close()
```

но бот просто не реагирует на новые сообщения от 2 бота, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Телеграм запрещает ботам общаться с другими ботами, единственный способ это сделать юзербота, но это уже совершенно другой вопрос

Comment: и как мне это сделать?

Comment: Интернет в помощь

Comment: не нашел ничего

Comment: ошибка, когда перехожу на сайт

Comment: [ссылка](https://www.google.com/search?q=как+сделать+юзер+бота)